# Using multiple images and to display at random

Tags: objective-c

How could I make it randomize what image shows up so that there is a different one displaying every time. Here is my code, and the images I want to add to get randomized are for instance "tutorial2.png" and "tutorial3.png". Where would I add them into this line of code so that it randomizing which one is displayed. I'm not too experience either so detail and code would be appreciated, thanks.

```
self.help=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"tutorial.png"];
self.help.position=ccp(ws.width/2,ws.height*4/4/2);
[self addChild:self.help];
```

Comment: There is plenty of question with Random. What did you try?

Comment: @Larme Well I havnt tried much of anything cause i havnt found anything posted to try. I'm not sure if people are over thinking what I'm trying to do but I couldn't be more clear. I just want the game to randomly pick one of the 3 images to show every time that the screen with this image is shown. I was thinking it would simple and to just seperate with commas like spriteWithFile:@"tutorial.png", "tutorial2.png"...etc. But this doesnt work. any help is appreciated and detail too cause I'm not an expert of any kind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You first add images to Array eg: theArray.

then using following code to get random index

```
NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [theArray count];
```

then.

```
self.help=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theArray[i]]]];
self.help.position=ccp(ws.width/2,ws.height*4/4/2);
[self addChild:self.help];
```

Comment: arc4random isn't optimal if the count of objects isn't a power of 2. further information: http://nshipster.com/random/

Comment: honestly i dont know what any of that means, what is the array and how and why do i add images to it? can i just somehow use a more simple method to just add a few more images to this line of code?